# Quick access to rows by index in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with huge dataframes and need to access and modify values for some rows that I access using their indexes.

```
df[start:end,]$column <- value
```

The problem is that, when start and end are too high, the time to access these rows becomes too much. For example, accessing `df[1:2,]` is almost immediate, but accessing `df[100000001:100000002,]` takes several minutes, which results on this approach to be impractical.

There must be a way for a faster access, because running `which(df$column1==value1)` with `value1` being specific for element in row (e.g. 100000001) only takes a few seconds. However as you can guess, accessing the dataframe using the indexes returned by `which` does not solve the problem, as it will be in the end the same kind of access as in the example above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it better, when you coerce the dataframe to a matrix? `m <- as.matrix(df)` Another variant is using `df[start:end, "column"] <- value` or `df$column[start:end] <- value`

Comment: Is there a comma missing in your example `df[100000001:100000002]`? Like this those are *columns*, not rows.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Edited, yes, it was a typo

Comment: @jogo Indeed, coercing into a matrix is much quicker!! It works even for higher numbers than that in the example. **EDIT**: I am wondering, why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but test which of proposed solution by @jogo is the fastest. It seem that changing from `data.frame` to `matrix` is the way to go.

```
library(microbenchmark)
dta <- data.frame(x= rnorm(10000), y= rnorm(10000))
dta_m <- as.matrix(dta)
microbenchmark(
    fast = {dta[1:20, ]$x <- 4},
    fast2 = {dta[1:20,"x"] <- 4},
    fast3 = {dta$x[1:20] <- 4},
    fast_matrix = {dta_m[1:20,"x"] <- 4},
    slow = {dta[9980:10000, ]$x <- 4},
    slow2 = {dta[9980:10000,"x"] <- 4},
    slow3 = {dta$x[9980:10000] <- 4},
    slow_matrix = {dta_m[9980:10000,"x"] <- 4}, times=50)
```

result

```
   Unit: microseconds
        expr  min   lq    mean median    uq   max neval
        fast 87.9 95.2 111.390 106.15 113.8 219.0    50
       fast2 31.3 33.8  38.818  36.05  39.9  89.1    50
       fast3 13.0 14.7  18.462  15.85  17.6  66.5    50
 fast_matrix  1.1  1.8   2.600   2.10   2.5  22.8    50
        slow 89.0 96.3 109.822 108.80 112.3 182.8    50
       slow2 31.9 33.9  40.446  38.30  41.0 105.0    50
       slow3 13.4 15.5  19.544  16.45  18.4  65.8    50
 slow_matrix  1.1  1.5   2.084   2.15   2.5   3.2    50
```